# What is the difference between these PHP arrays?

Tags: php

What is the difference between the following two lines? Both are working.

```
$sani = ['age' => '9 month', 'name' => 'alexsander', 'hairColor' => 'black',  ];
$sani = [$age ='9 month'; $name = 'alexsander'; $hairColor ='black';];
```

Comment: Second code __does not work__ - proof https://3v4l.org/kBirj

Comment: First one is valid, second is not because of the `;` between instead of `,`, assignments `=` instead of `=>`, and assumes all variables are set (which they might not be).

Answer (score 0):

These instructions are **not** equivalent. Plus, your second instruction is syntactically invalid.

The [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) clearly states the syntax to create arrays.